# Can I implement a trait which adds information to an external type in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I just implemented a simple trait to keep the history of a struct property:

```
fn main() {
    let mut weight = Weight::new(2);
    weight.set(3);
    weight.set(5);
    println!("Current weight: {}. History: {:?}", weight.value, weight.history);
}

trait History<T: Copy> {
    fn set(&mut self, value: T);
    fn history(&self) -> &Vec<T>;
}

impl History<u32> for Weight {
    fn set(&mut self, value: u32) {
        self.history.push(self.value);
        self.value = value;
    }
    fn history(&self) -> &Vec<u32> {
        &self.history
    }
}

pub struct Weight {
    value: u32,
    history: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Weight {
    fn new(value: u32) -> Weight {
        Weight {
            value,
            history: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

I don't expect this is possible, but could you add the `History` trait (or something equivalent) to something which doesn't already have a `history` property (like `u32` or `String`), effectively tacking on some information about which values the variable has taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Traits cannot add data members to the existing structures. Actually, only a programmer can do that by modifying the definition of a structure. Wrapper structures or hash-tables are the ways to go.

Answer (score 2):

No, traits can only contain behavior, not data. But you could make a struct.

If you could implement `History` for `u32`, you'd have to keep the entire history of *every* `u32` object indefinitely, in case one day someone decided to call `.history()` on it. (Also, what would happen when you assign one `u32` to another? Does its history come with it, or does the new value just get added to the list?)

Instead, you probably want to be able to mark *specific* `u32` objects to keep a history. A wrapper struct, as [red75prime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47364654/3650362) suggests, will work:

```
mod hist {
    use std::mem;

    pub struct History<T> {
        value: T,
        history: Vec<T>,
    }

    impl<T> History<T> {
        pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
            History {
                value,
                history: Vec::new(),
            }
        }

        pub fn set(&mut self, value: T) {
            self.history.push(mem::replace(&mut self.value, value));
        }

        pub fn get(&self) -> T
        where
            T: Copy,
        {
            self.value
        }

        pub fn history(&self) -> &[T] {
            &self.history
        }
    }
}
```

It's generic, so you can have a `History<u32>` or `History<String>` or whatever you want, but the `get()` method will only be implemented when the wrapped type is `Copy`.* Your `Weight` type could just be an alias for `History<u32>`. [Here it is in the playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d334dc06b94293d1d843e85607574a09&version=stable)

Wrapping this code in a module is a necessary part of maintaining the abstraction. That means you can't write `weight.value`, you have to call `weight.get()`. If `value` were marked `pub`, you could assign directly to `weight.value` (bypassing `set`) and then `history` would be inaccurate.

As a side note, you [*almost never*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/3650362) want `&Vec<T>` when you can use `&[T]`, so I changed the signature of `history()`. Another thing you might consider is returning an iterator over the previous values (perhaps in reverse order) instead of a slice.

---

* A better way of getting the `T` out of a `History<T>` is to implement `Deref` and write `*foo` instead of `foo.get()`.